# SWI Prolog give all variables in list of lists specific value

Tags: prolog

I have a List like this: `[[X,Y],[X],[Y],[X,Y,Z]]`.

Now I want to give every free Variable of X the value "true". Like:

```
?- assign_val(X,[[X,Y],[X],[Y],[X,Y,Z]], true, R).
R = [[true,Y],[true],[Y],[true,Y,Z]]
```

How to archive this?

Comment: At the Prolog prompt, enter: `R = [[X,Y],[X],[Y],[X,Y,Z]], X = true.` and see what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not different variables, there is only *one* variable `X` that simply occurs multiple times.

You thus can simply assign `true` to `X`. The fact that this item in an expression is irrelevant. You can implement this as:

```
assign_val(X, R, X, R).
```

But as you see, the `R` is not necessary here.